# Не могу применить z-index

Tags: css

При наведении на ссылку должен появляться блок, но он уходит под другие блоки.

http://prntscr.com/8f1vqs

Хотя для него задан `z-index` :

```
.moduletable_cart .cart_content {
    border: 1px solid #4c7898;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 500ms;
    -moz-transition: 500ms;
    -o-transition: 500ms;
    -ms-transition: 500ms;
    transition: 500ms;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
.moduletable_cart:hover .cart_content {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1;
    top: 116px;
    right: -1px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

что можете посоветовать мне , пожалуйста ?

Comment: Без кода элементов на которых происходит перекрытие сложно что-либо сказать. Когда применяется opacity z-index не адекватно работает порой. Могу посоветовать прочитать статью http://habrahabr.ru/post/166435/

Comment: Да, дайте html код страницы. Вообще смущает css - вы работаете с прозрачностью, может стоит работать со свойством `display` ?

Comment: @RussCoder, display нельзя анимировать, поэтому и opacity.

Comment: Покажи работающий пример с разметкой.

Answer (score 4):

z-index не работает без явно заданного position.
задайте тому же элементу position: relative (или absolute, или fixed - в зависимости от контекста), и все сработает.

Comment: дополню: незаданный `position` это `static`, он означает - игнорировать любые способы позиционирования, в т.ч. z-index

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте все остальные элементы на позиционирование и наличие `z-index`. Возможно другие элементы имеют большее значение `z-index`.

И было бы не плохо увидеть весь код данной проблемы. Можно например залить код [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net) и дать ссылку.